# How well does Sync Framework 4 scale?

Tags: .net, synchronization, scalability, microsoft-sync-framework

I've had a little experience with sync 2 and found that it performed terribly for even relatively small datasets (5000 rows or so).  I'm coming up to a new project and since the 4.0 CTP is out I was wondering if anyone had any luck with it.

I have a fairly large DB to sync (50 + tables with upto around 100,000 rows each).  Before I head down the road of testing it I thought I'd reach out to the community and see if anyone has tried something similar.

Comment: Good question. This may be interesting for you http://ayende.com/blog/4829/ravenfs-amp-rsync

Comment: which db are you using client and server side?

Comment: It's a bit stating the obvious, but I've seen phenomenal performance improvements in SyncFX2.1 just by adding indexes on all FK's and columns used in filters.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that SyncFX 2.1 added support for bulk inserts/updates which would have a dramatic effect when dealing with large datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sync Fx v4 is mostly around supporting Silverlight, Windows Phone 7 and other devices. It still uses Sync Fx v2.1 under the hood. unfortunately, they've [postponed](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/synclab/thread/2c6f1ab8-fed4-4c43-9a55-93002a9a8e02) the release and will release some part of the CTP as code samples instead.

am not sure which providers you used with v2, but the 2.1 release includes bulk procedures using TVPs and this coupled with the use of DatasetSurrogate improves the memory usage and performance compared with prior releases.

Comment: Ah,..that's shockingly disappointing.  I guess the answer is to hand crank it then.  Obviously I'm not gonna sync the entire DB to the client,..that would be stupid but I hoped it would be able to handle a couple of hundred thousand rows or so.  Never mind.

Comment: i'd still use it for synching and focus on performance tuning rather than building one from scratch and worrying about change tracking, change enumeration, change application, conflict detection/resolution, etc...